# RegEx query to find all groups of 2 characters where lines are different lengths

Tags: regex

I have a document that contains lines of characters in groups of 2. I want to use a regular expression to find each of these groups however the lines of characters are different lengths.

```
88 00 02 00 E9 07 58 0F 08 8F 
88 00 02 00 E9 07 58 0F 
89 08 02 00 E9 07 58 0F 05
```

the RegEx I currently have looks like this:

```
\s(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)\s?(\w+)\s?(\w+)\s?(\w+)$
```

The issue I am having is for the shorter lines it is splitting the last few groups into single character groups instead of double. For example it is giving me:

```
'88' '00' '02' '00' 'E9' '07' '5' '8' '0' 'F'
```

When I need:

```
'88' '00' '02' '00' 'E9' '07' '58' '0F' '' ''
```

any help on how to achieve this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Reorganize `\s?(\w+)` into `(?:\s+(\w+))?` or `(?:\s+(\w{2}))?`

Comment: Why don't you split on space?

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew that's done the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `(\w+)\s?(\w+)\s?(\w+)\s?(\w+)$` part matches smaller lines, backtracking mechanism forces the regex engine to find matching variants and since `\s?` does not have to match any char, and `\w+` can match 1 char, the result contains single char capture.

You need to replace all `\s?(\w+)` with `(?:\s+(\w+))?` or `(?:\s+(\w{2}))?` to make sure the whitespaces are matched 1 or more times and `\w{2}` can ensure it will always match and capture 2 word chars.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this without regex using the following:

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##dY5BCsIwFETXzSn@Lq2EEpViKnRpL1GKuGj1Q0xCfpTUy8cGwZVuZvHeDIxbws2afUp4d9YHwDD5YK0mxoigg4EVXCmQEuQu56kFeYBmJT1IBarn4n/j49pc/LFuVj2yGLuB8xE2sJVsth4I0ADRkRXOownlsEDGUSxZaKRQfk/WL3Rnbc11WmmMgmpyGkNZCZhR6@dFP6aO86oaq5Te)

```
import itertools

ss = [
    '88 00 02 00 E9 07 58 0F 08 8F',
    '88 00 02 00 E9 07 58 0F',
    '89 08 02 00 E9 07 58 0F 05',
]
xx=[''] * 10
for s in ss:
    print([y for x,y in list(itertools.zip_longest(xx, s.split(), fillvalue=''))])
```

This uses `itertools.zip_longest` to merge the empty list (`xx` - initialized to 10 empty strings) with the result from `s.split()` ran against each line of text to preserve the number of elements in the result.

Outputs:

```
['88', '00', '02', '00', 'E9', '07', '58', '0F', '08', '8F']
['88', '00', '02', '00', 'E9', '07', '58', '0F', '', '']
['89', '08', '02', '00', 'E9', '07', '58', '0F', '05', '']
```